# Python 3.5.1 from PixelAcces Objects to CSV dataset

Tags: python, image, csv, python-imaging-library, pixel

I am working on a project in Python about taking images and then analyzing these using statistical methods.

I am (very) new to Python and I have thus problems handling data.

I want to export my image data from Python to a csv-format making it easier to analyze it in another program.

So if the first cell in the first row has the RGB-value [100,50,200] then I want it transformed to [100050200].

I think I need to setup a loop going over all the cells. But how to do it and how to make it 3 digit numbers for each of the R, G and B values - I do not know.

```
from PIL import Image
im=Image.open('path.jpeg')
pixels=list(im.getdata())
```

And then I am lost. All kind of help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what Michael Staniek answered

Okay, your Raspberry takes pictures that you want to convert to a CSV file. The way this works is like this:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy
img=Image.open(pathtoimage)
imgarray=numpy.array(img)
```

You open the file with PIL, which returns an img object which you can then convert into a numpy array.
The Array will be 3dimensional, so it will look like this:

```
array([[[1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3]],
       [[1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3]],
       [[1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3]]])
```

You can then use the following code:

```
for row in imgarray:
    outputstring=""
    for column in row:
        valuestring=""
        for value in column:
            if value < 10:
                valuestring+="00"+str(value)
            elif value < 100:
                valuestring+="0"+str(value)
            else:
                valuestring+=str(value)
       outputstring+=valuestring+";"
    print(outputstring[:-1]) #excluding the last letter, because its a ;
```

This will give you the following result:

001002003;001002003;001002003
001002003;001002003;001002003
001002003;001002003;001002003